# How to make a "Like Gate"

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-fql, gate

I would like to be able to check if a visitor has liked an **arbitrary** site.  That is, without have to get permissions or login or interact any way with Facebook from our site.

At first I thought I could use FQL but I need access to the visitors user id.  Then I thought maybe I could scrape the Like box but I don't seem to be able to scrape it as that iFrame is locked down.

Not possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The only way to do this was for the user to login and you check data in `/me/likes` which is gated behind the `user_likes` permission.

However, it is now against Facebook's policies to gate an app or app content based on if a person has liked something, so your use case isn't supported technically or by policy.